# Bootstrap Theme Not Showing Correctly

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Starting my first ASP.NET website, following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs). I have got to the point of changing the theme, downloading the css file and adding it to the Content folder and updating BundleConfig.cs but the theme has not applied! Unsure what I have done wrong.

I have tried other themes (from bootswatch.com), but the same issue. I assume I have not done something correctly.

Below is the BundleConfig.cs which I updated.

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen.css",  //Updated from bootstrap.css
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

It should look like the top one, instead it looks like the bottom:

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIG4m.png)

Comment: Have you checked the browser Network tab (Press F12 key and then click Network tab) for any errors?

Comment: No comments stating errors.